# Invalid post back when button type is Button in datapager

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a listview and datapager inside an update panel. The button type is set as button. Now the problem is that when I click the Next / Previous buttons I get the following error.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback
>   or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I did some googling and found that I need to set EventValidation as false. But when I do this I get a blank page.

Kindly let me know what needs to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to switch off event validation in "<%@Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>. Would be good If you show main code block.

Answer (score 4):

Put this code in `Page_Load` event

```
if (!IsPostBack)
  {
     BindData();
  }
```

And do not forget modify the `PagePropertiesChanged` Event of `ListViews` :

```
protected void lstProducts_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindData();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

'EnableEventValidation=true' is ASP.NET protection from tampering of POST-requests (POST injection attack). In your case this error point to dynamic changing page markup on clientside by yourself.

You can resolve problem via disabling this option - <%@Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>, or registering your event by [RegisterForEventValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerforeventvalidation.aspx).